# Javascript Python process communication

Tags: javascript, python

I have 2 processes

A javascript and a python process

the python process needs to peroidically send data to the javascript process

I would like to avoid using a socket server or http

the 2 processes are on the same host by the same user

How do I do this ?

Comment: This isn't a **language** question, it's an **environment** question. What environment is the JavaScript process running in? Node.js? Deno? Something else? Similarly, what environment is the Python code running in? CPython? Something else? What research have you done into what interprocess communication options other than sockets there are in those environments?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the specific options you've listed? Without knowing the underlying reasons, it's likely that once we list other options, you'll realize you don't want to use those either for the same reasons.

Comment: FIFO aka named pipes could do the trick.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe